# Unable to connect to neo4j using neo4j java driver

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm unable to connect to Neo4j VERSION 2.2.5 using neo4j-java-driver version Maven version 1.0.5

Below is my code

```
    Config noSSL = Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig();

    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost",AuthTokens.basic("neo4j","root"),noSSL);
    Session session = driver.session();

    String query = "MATCH (n:test) RETURN n LIMIT 25";

    StatementResult result =session.run(query);

//  StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title" );
    while ( result.hasNext() )
    {
        Record record = result.next();
        System.out.println( record.get("author"));
      //  System.out.println( record.get( "title" ).asString() + " " + record.get("name").asString() );
    }

    session.close();
    driver.close();
```

But Im getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to connect to 'localhost' on port 7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

Do I need to edit something in neo4j-server.properties file ? as Im using the default. Except I have edited the line

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: is the database running, if you go to the neo4j browser on localhost:7474 is it working ?

Comment: Yes it is working

Comment: Infact I did  sudo ufw allow 7687 also

Comment: what does `telnet 127.0.0.1 7687` returns ?

Comment: It says connected , anyways I upgraded my neo4j version to 3.0.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: I should have asked that in the beginning :). I didn't see you edited the question with the neo4j version !  Bolt is only available in 3.0+ Glad it is working

Comment: If I may ask which Java API I should use to connect to neo4j 2.2.5 ?

Comment: Bolt connections only work for Neo4j 3.X versions

Comment: I faced a similar problem Neo4j 3.5.2 and resolved it by updating settings 

 `dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687`